# Array objects of calls are set to NULL and not set to constructor values

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have a class that only has public `automatic properties of strings` like Name, ID, LastName and also I have defiend a constructor for it and defiend them as `string.Empty` too.
Now in the code I create an array of this class like this:

```
AlternateAddressSummary[] alternateAddressSummaries = new AlternateAddressSummary[6];
int adrsCounter = -1;
foreach (Addresses adrs in address_alternative)
{
    adrsCounter++;
    FillAlternateAddressSummaryObject(alternateAddressSummaries[adrsCounter], adrs);
}
```

And `FillAlternateAddressSummaryObject` is just filling the properties of each object for example:

```
private void FillAlternateAddressSummaryObject(AlternateAddressSummary alA, Addresses adrs)
{
    alA.AlternateAdressLine1 = adrs.City;
    //...
}
```

But why do I get `NULL` exception on `alA`?  Even when I create those 6 array objects, they are initialized to `NULL`. Shouldn't they be set to what I say in the `constructor`?

Comment: show all relevant code please as well as how you were setting items to string.Empty.. also are you familiar with how to use `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` Method and from there you can write your own little class to set the null initial values to string.Empty as well

Comment: You are not creating 6 objects in an array. You are creating 6 references to objects and references default to null. You still need to create the objects by invoking the constructor.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you didn't instantiate any of the members of `alternateAddressSummaries`

what you did is kinda like doing this

```
AlternateAddressSummary1;
AlternateAddressSummary2;
AlternateAddressSummary3;
...
```

You've declared an **array** of `AlternateAddressSummary`, but you haven't actually instantiated any of them.  they're still all `null`

---

if you did this

```
for(int i=0; i<alternateAddressSummaries.Length; i++)
{
    alternateAddressSummaries[i]= new AlternateAddressSummary(/*params*/);
}
```

they would be instantiated and their values would be whatever your constructor set them to.

Comment: Thanks but gives error saying address can't be both in the for-each loop and also changing it inside the loop

Comment: @ConfusedSleepyDeveloper good point.  I've changed the answer to use a regular for loop